# What is the complexity of string.encode()?

Tags: python, string

I am wondering about the complexity of pythons `string.encode()` function. Is it linear or worse?

Comment: What did you find when you measured it?

Comment: I have not measured it yet. Looking at the algorithm (which I don't have) is more precise. That is why I am asking :)

Comment: In case you are talking about CPython, the source code is freely available for you to inspect: https://github.com/python/cpython

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `string.encode()` is just a function that encodes one character to another in different encoding, the worst complexity can be `O(n)` when all characters need to be replaced. Thus the function is linear.

Edit: to consider even the lookup phase for the character just for understanding:

Dictionaries are used for translating a character into another character. looking up for an element in a dictionary is considered to be of complexity `O(1)`. Final complexity stays `O(n)` in worst case.